# Filtering out duplicate results by max value from single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to filter out results from a table by maximum STAMP column. The result I need is for every Duplicate ID number to filter out so I have single ID numbers with the maximum stamp.

**EDIT :** Column definitions -

**doe** - datetime       **var** - varvarchar(4) latin1_swedish_ci     **ID** - varchar(9)  latin1_swedish_ci  **Stamp** - bigint(20)

the data below is a small snippet  -

```
DATE                VAR      ID     STAMP
01/09/2014 00:05    WEBN    13279   212276333136568000
01/09/2014 00:06    WEBN    13084   212276333179962000
01/09/2014 00:07    WEBN    13084   212276333236687000
01/09/2014 00:25    WEBN    13192   212276334356964000
01/09/2014 00:28    WEBN    13433   212276334517114000
01/09/2014 00:29    WEBN    13433   212276334574072000
01/09/2014 00:54    WEBN    13261   212276336085970000
01/09/2014 01:24    WEBN    13208   212276337880800000
01/09/2014 01:26    WEBN    13208   212276337972060000
01/09/2014 01:41    WEBN    13256   212276338901120000
01/09/2014 02:07    WEBN    13225   212276340440626000
01/09/2014 02:28    WEBN    13048   212276341700449000
01/09/2014 02:29    WEBN    13048   212276341789222000
01/09/2014 02:31    WEBN    13217   212276341897262000
01/09/2014 03:21    WEBN    13464   212276344870866000
01/09/2014 03:22    WEBN    13464   212276344970040000
01/09/2014 04:01    WEBN    13486   212276347260517000
01/09/2014 04:02    WEBN    13486   212276347351666000
01/09/2014 05:14    WEBN    13490   212276351690524000
01/09/2014 05:16    WEBN    13490   212276351776728000
01/09/2014 17:55    WEBN    13393   212276397317713000
01/09/2014 18:17    WEBN    13253   212276398658967000
```

The query below is what I'm using.

```
    CREATE TABLE SPC_VARCOLL AS SELECT m.* FROM var_x m 
WHERE m.DATE BETWEEN '2014-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-09-30 23:59:59'
AND m.VAR= 'WEBN' 
AND m.STAMP = (SELECT MAX(m.STAMP) FROM var_x m2 WHERE m2.ID= m.ID)
```

It does filter duplicate results, but seems to filter out non duplicates too? I'm only getting 45 results in the new created table, where I should be getting more like 1000.

Any ideas?

Comment: So just to be clear, you want only those records in your result that have STAMP = <maximum STAMP value>?

Comment: Sorry, for every duplicate ID I want the maximum stamp row

Comment: Is this [tag:mysql] or [tag:oracle] Enterprise Database? Surely, it cannot be both.

Comment: I think you will have to apply the DATE and VAR filters to your subquery as well to get the desired result, because the maximum STAMP value might not be in the filtered set.

Comment: MySql, a pop up came up to say select oracle too as it would get more answers? I've removed it now

Comment: @Grüse So have two where statements, once outside sub query and once inside?

Comment: Check my answer and see if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are AND-ing three filters:

```
WHERE m.DATA BETWEEN ...
m.VAR = 'WEBN'
m.STAMP = <subquery>
```

The issue here is that your subquery does not apply the top two filters again. Let's say you have this simple data set:

```
DATE                VAR     ID  STAMP
01/09/2014 00:01    WEBN    1   100
01/09/2014 00:05    WEBN    1   101
01/09/2014 00:01    WEBN    2   200
01/09/2014 00:25    WEBN    2   201
```

Now if we execute your query (note the date filter)

```
SELECT m.* FROM var_x m 
WHERE m.DATE BETWEEN '2014-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-09-01 00:20:00'
AND m.VAR= 'WEBN' 
AND m.STAMP = (SELECT MAX(m.STAMP) FROM var_x m2 WHERE m2.ID= m.ID)
```

we get the following result

```
01/09/2014 00:05    WEBN    1   101
```

Why is ID 2 not in there? Because it does not meet the subquery's criteria, because the MAX value is "global", while you're looking for a filtered MAX. Specifically, the subquery's result for ID = 2 is 201, but that record is not in the filtered time range (between 00:00 and 00:20), therefore it will get filtered out.

Using this query

```
SELECT m.* FROM var_x m 
WHERE m.DATE BETWEEN '2014-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-09-01 00:20:00'
AND m.VAR= 'WEBN' 
AND m.STAMP = (
    SELECT MAX(m2.STAMP) 
    FROM var_x m2 
    WHERE m2.ID= m.ID
    AND m2.DATE BETWEEN '2014-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-09-01 00:20:00'
    AND m2.VAR= 'WEBN' 
)
```

should yield the desired result.

Comment: Tried your query, I'm getting a lot more results, but now getting duplicates?

Comment: sorry, duplicate ID's with different Stamps

Comment: Half numeric and half with text + numbers , sorry I should of pointed that out, the data is just a snippet

Comment: Could you add your table definition to the question?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Mysql what do you mean by table definition?

Comment: The table definition is your table's layout, I'm talking about var_x here. At some point you probably defined its columns and what kind of data they contain (via CREATE TABLE for instance). That is the table definition I'm looking for.

Comment: Updated with column definitions, hope this helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63209/discussion-between-gruse-and-engl12).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why your query wouldn't work. You can get the expected result count with:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM var_x m 
WHERE m.DATE BETWEEN '2014-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-09-30 23:59:59'
  AND m.VAR= 'WEBN'
GROUP BY m.ID
;
```

I have another solution with Oracle 11g and above, with recent aggregate operators:

```
SELECT max(m.DATE)  keep (dense_rank last order by m.STAMP) DATE,
       max(m.VAR)   keep (dense_rank last order by m.STAMP) VAR,
       m.ID,
       max(m.STAMP) keep (dense_rank last order by m.STAMP) STAMP
FROM var_x m 
WHERE m.DATE BETWEEN '2014-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-09-30 23:59:59'
  AND m.VAR= 'WEBN'
GROUP BY m.ID
;
```

Comment: will this work in mysql? I only selected oracle as there was a popup saying I would get more answers?

Comment: I guess not - of course more people will be concerned by your issue if you select an inappropriate tag, but you will get inappropriate answers like this one.